# Not able to Connect to hbase through phoenix

Tags: hadoop, hbase

When i am trying to connect to hbase through phoenix, i am getting the following errors.

```
6/08/25 17:59:15 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/08/25 17:59:17 WARN client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Encountered problems when prefetch hbase:meta table:
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: Cannot find row in hbase:meta for table: SYSTEM.CATALOG, row=SYSTEM.CATALOG,,99999999999999
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.prefetchRegionCache(HConnectionManager.java:1159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:1223)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1068)
```

Comment: Also getting the following errors Error: ERROR 2006 (INT08): Incompatible jars detected between client and server. Ensure that phoenix.jar is put on the classpath of HBase in every region server: ERROR 1012 (42M03): Table undefined. tableName=SYSTEM.CATALOG (state=INT08,code=2006)

Comment: first you clear off "Incompatible jars " this might be the primary reason and also format the content nicely, before posting the question

Comment: Incompatible jars - might be hbase client version(may be old) and server version(may be new) mismatch

Comment: I have used phoenix-4.2.0-bin for phoenix. Moreover plaaced phoenix-4.2.0-client.jar  and phoenix-4.2.0-server.jar inside lib of hbase. But still when i am trying to connect to phoenix, getting the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have specified the table name correctly, phoenix tables are case sensitive.